# Oracle datetime compare based on format

Tags: sql, oracle

In the Oracle, how to do this date compare if column type is datetime ? I want to keep the string format 'MM/dd/yyyy' .

how to do this ?

Thanks

```
select * from my_tbl
where mycol >= '07/11/2012'
```

Comment: I'd convert the incoming date parameter to a datetime, probably with something like `TO_DATE()`.  And remember all ranges should be lower-bound inclusive, upper-bound exclusive.  Actually, depending on context, it may be better to start with a timestamp in your application code.  In any case, converting every row in your table is a terrible idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that date means July 11th:

```
select * 
from my_tbl
where mycol >= to_date('07/11/2012', 'MM/DD/YYYY');
```

If that date should be November 7th:

```
select * 
from my_tbl
where mycol >= to_date('07/11/2012', 'DD/MM/YYYY');
```

Depending on how you fill in the values for mycol, you might want to get rid of the time part as well:

```
select * 
from my_tbl
where trunc(mycol) >= to_date('07/11/2012', 'DD/MM/YYYY');
```

Comment: In the specific example of your third `SELECT`, the `TRUNC` precludes the use of any index that might be on `mycol`; in this case, the `TRUNC` is unnecessary, because if `TRUNC(mycol)` is greater than or equal to some date at midnight, then `mycol` will also always be greater than or equal to that same date value.